# Nested foreach loop in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have problem with my nested `foreach`. As you see in the screenshot, it just returns all data in every dt.

[image: data example]

I know how to solve my problem with a partial view. But I just want to know is there solution with foreach or some other loop.

```
public class VM
{
    public IEnumerable<x> Upi { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<y> Adre { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Upi)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var smece in Model.Adre)
                { 
                    <div>
                        <pre>
                             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => smece.Ul) 
                             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => smece.Ku), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => smece.Gr)
                        </pre>
                    </div>
                 }
            </td>
```

Comment: Is it just one Y per X?

Comment: No, I just changed names if somebody who knows me sees this. Its part of bigger model.

Comment: As you showed the output can you describe or show the expected result

Comment: I just want for asdas to stay up and rzrtz... to go in lower. In both Ienumerable there is AU_ID field(primary in Adre forgein in Upis)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I am stupid. It was simple. I just had to put one if. 
if (smece.AU_ID == item.AU_ID) before pre and it works. TY all. Now only problem is, is there maybe other way where it doesnt need to iterate whole foreach and just go to direct AU_ID.

Comment: Ok, I found solution for that also. Freach should look like this:  @foreach (var smece in Model.Adre.Where(smece=>mece.AU_ID==item.AU_ID). No need for if.